# Dealing with extremely large numbers

Tags: java, int, largenumber

So I have to deal with really large numbers. In fact, the exact number is 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 which is 2^64. I guess I could write it just as 2^64, but then I'm going to be subtracting numbers from it and dividing and whatever, and some of my calculations might also be in the quintillions. I tried adding "L" to the end of it like so:

```
public int total = 18446744073709551616L;
```

However, it is still giving me the same error as the integer being too large. I'm not sure if this is because I'm typing it in wrong or it is still too large even with the 'L'. Any solution around this? I'm definitely willing to expend a bit of processing power or adding extra runtime, as long as it works. Merci!

Comment: Read up on the `BigInteger` class. The largest `long` is 2^63-1.

Comment: You can't store that size number in an `int`. You can't even store that size number in a `long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Create the BigInteger from a string, using `new BigInteger("18446744073709551616")`.

You can perform mathematical operations by calling methods, such as `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, `divide` and `mod`. You cannot use the `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%` operators as they only work on primitive types (and `+` on Strings).

Comment: Note: You could alternatively use `new BigInteger(2).pow(64)` as rgettman's deleted answer suggested. You can't use `new BigInteger(18446744073709551616)` as that would require the number to fit in an `int` to start with.

Comment: Ah, these answers are all great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, but I have one last question. It seems that I can only use the functions of add, subtract and multiply and whatever with two BigIntegers. What if I want to do total.multiply(12) or something simple like that? What is the easiest way of getting around this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your case only BigInteger or BigDecimal will be solution.